# Repeated id in children tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-integrity

I'm wondering what the pros and cons of having a repeated id in child tables in a database.

For example, consider a table `parent`:

```
create table parent (
  id int,
  a text,
  b text
)
```

And this `parent` has a `child1` table that references it:

```
create table child1 (
  id int,
  parent_id int not null references parent(id),
  c text,
  d text
)
```

All fine and good, and nothing out of the ordinary. The problem comes in as you keep drilling down:

```
create table child2 (
  id int,
  child1_id int not null references child1(id),
  e text,
  f text
)

create table child3 (
  id int,
  child2_id int not null references child2(id),
  g text,
  h text
)
```

The issue I'm having is, the further you get down, the more tedious it becomes to join your way upwards.  One solution I've considered is to repeat the `parent` id in all the children tables:

```
create table child2 (
  id int,
  parent_id int not null references parent(id),
  child1_id int not null references child1(id),
  e text,
  f text
)

create table child3 (
  id int,
  parent_id int not null references parent(id),
  child2_id int not null references child2(id),
  g text,
  h text
)
```

This helps reduce the number of joins, but it also affects database integrity. You need to always remember to update all the `parent_id` columns if you switch the parent of `child1`. My question is: are there any other approaches to handle this situation? If not, is there any way to repeat an id in children tables while still retaining data integrity?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your example it's important that the relation goes parent<-child1<-child2 and not parent<-child1 and parent<-child2.

So how about something like this.

```
create table parent 
(
  id int,
  a text,
  b text
);

create table child 
(
  id int,
  parent_id int null references parent(id),
  previous_child_id int null references child(id)
  c text,
  d text
);
```

A second approach that is more normalized would be this. This assumes that the id on parent_child can be assumed to be an increasing integer so you can always figure out order of the children.

```
create table parent 
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  a text,
  b text
);

create table child 
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int null references parent(id),
  previous_child_id int null references child(id)
  c text,
  d text
);

create table parent_child
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int null references parent(id),
  child_id int null references child(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @JustKim is OK, but you can go even further

```
create table person
(
  id int,
  parent_id int null references person(id),
  c text,
  d text
);
```

If parent_id is null, that record is parent.

Of course, to get all children of one parent, you have to use recursion in your code.